# String into NSDate Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp, nsdate

I obtain the following string from my JSON response :

`2016-05-24 17:13:08`

I use the following code to parse it into an `NSDate` :

```
if let messagedate = onemessage["timestamp"] as? String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(messagedate)
    curr_message.date = date
   }
```

where `curr_message` is of type `Message` initialised like this :

```
class Message : NSObject {
var id: String?
var text: String?
var date: NSDate?
var sender: Friend?
}
```

The problem is that the `curr_message.date` value is always `nil` after this `if` condition executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "HH" instead of "hh" for `dateFormatter.dateFormat`.

"hh" is for AM/PM format, "HH" is for 24 hours format, and you have the latter: `17:13:08`.